# Beautifulsoup extracting urls from a given website menu

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello every one I'm new to beautifulsoup, I'm trying to write a function that will be able to extract second level urls from a given website.

For example if I have this website url : `https://edition.cnn.com/` my function should be able to return

```
https://edition.cnn.com/world
https://edition.cnn.com/politics
https://edition.cnn.com/business
https://edition.cnn.com/health
https://edition.cnn.com/entertainment
https://edition.cnn.com/style
https://edition.cnn.com/travel
```

first I have tried this code to retrieve all links starting with the string of the url:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import lxml
import re
def getLinks(url):
  response = requests.get(url)
  data = response.text
  soup = bs4(data, 'lxml')
  links = []
  for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(str(url))):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
  return links
```

But then again the actual output is giving me all the links even links of articles which is not I'm looking for. is there a method that I can use to get what I want using regular expression or others.

Answer (score 2):

The links are inside `<nav>` tag, so using CSS selector `nav a[href]` will select only links inside `<nav>` tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://edition.cnn.com'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('nav a[href]'):
    if a['href'].count('/') > 1 or '#' in a['href']:
        continue
    print(url + a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://edition.cnn.com/world
https://edition.cnn.com/politics
https://edition.cnn.com/business
https://edition.cnn.com/health
https://edition.cnn.com/entertainment
https://edition.cnn.com/style
https://edition.cnn.com/travel
https://edition.cnn.com/sport
https://edition.cnn.com/videos
https://edition.cnn.com/world
https://edition.cnn.com/africa
https://edition.cnn.com/americas
https://edition.cnn.com/asia
https://edition.cnn.com/australia
https://edition.cnn.com/china
https://edition.cnn.com/europe
https://edition.cnn.com/india
https://edition.cnn.com/middle-east
https://edition.cnn.com/uk

...and so on.
```

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback, but this works only with  this website ,I have tried it to other website but it doesn't work , and as I said I want to be able to apply it  to a list of websites

Comment: @fati Every website has different structure and navigation. Some websites don't have any second level URLs etc. So for each website a parser must be made, or using some crawling program to extract urls.

Comment: yeah you are right every website has its own structure, but it seem that your code and mine will help me to cover already two types of website structures ( I'm still testing) which is cool, I just wanted to know if there is a simple method helping me to avoid returning links to articles like this :'http://www.example.ma/categorie/economie/article/6986-07-23-09-19-06-19' OR links ending with index.html in my code.

Comment: @fati I would recommend to look at `urllib.parse` module https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse

Comment: very useful Thank youu :).